# Finding post+comment block on instagram (selenium, python, chromedriver)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My goal is to be able to find the sizes & location on page of all of the Instagram (post+comment) blocks of users I follow. (large rectangle block of page below with picture on left and comments on right)

An example of this is the following:

1. go to https://www.instagram.com/zuck/
2. click on the first post

[image]

3. I am trying to `driver.find_element` the image with comments block in the center of the page above so that I can find the size & location on page of the block. The xpath I see is (`//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[1]`) and the div class begins with `_97aPb`, however, when I refresh or go to a different user these change.

So, I'm looking for an alternative way to find that element. I want to be able to click to the next post and be able to find the (post +comment) block for all posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get the article:

Depending if how opened the post, the contents will be under the div with `@role="dialog"` or `@id="react-root"`. If you open the post directly, there is no dialog but if you search for `'//div[@role="dialog" or @id="react-root"]//article` then the last one will be the post you are looking for.

So:

```py
article = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@role="dialog" or @id="react-root"]//article')[-1]
```

How to get the next image in the article:

```
next_image_arrow = article.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "coreSpriteRightChevron")]')
```

How to select the next article (available only when article opened in modal):

```py
next_article_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class, "coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")]')
```

How to get the comments:

```py
all_comments = article.find_elements_by_xpath('./div/section[2]/following-sibling::div/ul/ul')
```

The Xpath above means this:

- `/div/section[2]` << in the article node, get all nodes which have *a direct `div` child node which have at least 2 direct `section` tagged child nodes* and select the second one
- `/following-sibling::div/ul/ul` << take the found section nodes and if the section node is followed by a div and it has direct ul child nodes which have direct ul child nodes, return them

I hope this answers the question.

Comment: Thank you for your response an explanation. I was clicking on the right arrow to view all posts as you also suggested, so I am viewing all posts in a similar view as the picture above. I tried article = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@role="dialog" or @id="react-root"]//article')[-1], but I got an error TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable. So I tried article = driver.find_element_by_xpath(('//div[@role="dialog" or @id="react-root"]//article')[-1]), but then I got an error that there is no such element.

Comment: I tried inspecting the page and pasting '//div[@role="dialog" or @id="react-root"]//article'. I see two matches for this, the second being the image of the post. So not sure why element cant be found.

Comment: My mistake it should have been `find_elements_by_xpath`. Fixing in the answer now.

Comment: Thank you! One more question: I am trying to take a screenshot of those elements from reading the selenium api and viewing other questions on stack overflow I don't see why this doesn't work: article.screenshot_as_png('article.png')
            all_comments.screenshot_as_png('comments.png') Would appreciate your help on this. Thank you.

Comment: `all_comments.screenshot_as_png` << this supposed to be a list. You can't make a screenshot about a list. `article.screenshot_as_png('article.png')` << with this amount of information it is hard to tell. Open a new question where you provide information about what browser and driver you use and what error message you encounter when you try to make the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you. Will open a new question.

Comment: If my answer answers your original question, please accept it as an answer. :) Thanks

Comment: I did :) New question at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60999624/13143984