# Trying to take and save a screenshot of a specific element (selenium, python, chromedriver)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to take and save a screenshot of the image+comment block that can be seen by navigating to 
https://www.instagram.com/p/B9MjyquAfkE/. Below is a testable piece of my code.

I am getting an error:
article.screenshot_as_png('article.png')
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

It seems that the code is able to find article, but is having an issue with the screenshot. I am also trying to specify a certain location where I want to save my screenshot on my computer.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class bot:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("path to chrome driver here")

    def screenShot(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/B9MjyquAfkE/")
        time.sleep(2)
        #find post+comments block on page
        article = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@role="dialog" or @id="react-root"]//article')[-1]
        #take screenshot of the post+comments block 
        article.screenshot_as_png('article.png')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = bot()
    bot.screenShot()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try instead of

```
article.screenshot_as_png('article.png')
```

This:

```
screenshot_as_bytes = article.screenshot_as_png
with open('article.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(screenshot_as_bytes)
```

Explanation:

`article.screenshot_as_png` is already the screenshot in bytes, all you need to do is to save it. If you call it like `article.screenshot_as_png()` then the execution will be attempted on the bytes, hence the error: `TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable`

Comment: Thank you, with this I am now able to take the screenshot, but it is no longer of the article element specified.

Comment: You should have open a new issue if you have a new problem. Your original question was about **'why I can't make a screenshot**', now your problem is probably that **"I can make a screenshot but it is not from the element I want"**. But it is unclear what you managed to capture, did the page load or did the Instagram login dialog appear...